# @Html.Raw(Url.Action(...)) evaluated to empty string on deployment server

Tags: razor, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on localhost and my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("IdentityProviders", "Account", new { serviceNamespace = "traffictheory", appId = "http://traffictheory.cloudapp.net/" }))', ...
```

works just fine.

but on deployment server (Windows Azure cloud service), the url is empty : ''

I dont know where to start debugging.

Comment: [Fiddler (described here)](http://blogs.staykov.net/2010/08/how-to-debug-your-application-http.html) is a good way to start debugging web application.

Comment: Good to debug an MVC 4 project deployed on azure?

Comment: Good to debug **any** HTTP communication, hosted **anywhere**

Comment: Did you understand the problem. Server side code evaluating to ''?

Comment: well, I don't understand the problem, because it is not mine code running in mine deployment. What I am doing is giving you hints how to debug the AJAX calls and inspect what exactly is sent to the server and what comes out of it.

Comment: Thanks, but its not a ajax call that is the issue. Quote: "but on deployment server (Windows Azure cloud service), the url is empty : ''"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not missing any parameters required by the route to that action.

Also, make sure you didn't forget to mention the `area` in the parameters.

```
Url.Action("IdentityProviders", "Account",
    new {
        area = "did you forget the area?",
        serviceNamespace = "traffictheory",
        appId = "http://traffictheory.cloudapp.net/",
        requiredParamThatYouForgot = "missing value"
    })
```